# My main Index page embeds 2 other pages using Angular UI-Router; how can I get the Javascript file I'm loading in the Index to reach all 3 pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using UI-Router the main page loads 2 other pages within them.

1. Index --> loads CSS and JS (including "application.js") with a `<ui-view>` to Navigation
2. Navigation page --> has navigation HTML with another `<ui-view>` to Content
3. Content

So basically Index > Navigation > Content

The Index is loading "application.js" with `<script src="application.js">` at the bottom of the page.  it contains all the page functionality.

It's loading successfully as I put an alert in the window.load function to make sure.... but what I'm finding is that I think the code in there is not reaching the other 2 embedded pages

The code works successfully if I put all the code and combine them together from the Index, Navigation, and Content into one single page.  But not when separated but embedded together.

I tried putting:

```
<script src="~/assets/js/application.js"></script>
```

at the bottom of the Layout and Content but still didn't work..I'm guessing because technically it's loading as one page?  but it's not really one page?...

HOWEVER if I copy and paste everything within application.js into the Layout and Content.. it WILL work.

That's such a crappy way of doing it though.  How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: "code in there is not reaching the other ..." - what does this mean? If you are executing any js right inside `script` tags in Navigation and Content and that code relies on something from application.js, then you have to load application.js in the `head` of Index.

Comment: that's what I thought too, but it doesn't make sense if I copy and paste what's in the "application.js" into the Navigation file.. then the navigation works properly... despite the file already being loaded within the Index page

Comment: Please post relevant portions of your code instead of describing them.